# How to install two versions of MySQL on MacOS (High Sierra)?

Tags: macos, mysql, homebrew

I need two separate development environments in MacOS 10.13 to accommodate clients running different versions of MySQL on their servers (5.5 and 5.7.22). I've installed MySQL 5.7.22 from a package, but need to install a different environment and binary for 5.5 which won't conflict with the other.

There was once a way to accomplish this with Homebrew, but in 1.6.8 permitting separate /version directories seems to have been deprecated (?)

Comment: Read over https://gist.github.com/benlinton/d24471729ed6c2ace731 maybe a starting point... not sure though but read and keep digging otherwise.